# Isomorphisms define an equivalence relation between modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have recently started theory of modules and I have the following doubt:

Is "being isomorphic" an equivalence relation among $R$-modules?

Concretely, I am not sure that if $f$ is an $R$-module isomorphism, then $f^{-1}$ exists and it is also a $R$-module isomorphism.

Thanks.

Comment: If $f:M\to N$ is an $R$-module isomorphism, then in particular $f$ is a bijection so the mapping $f^{-1}:N\to M$ exists and for every $m\in M$ you can write $f^{-1}(f(m))=m$ and for every $n\in N$ you can write $f(f^{-1}(n))=n$. So $f^{-1}(n_1+n_2)= f^{-1}(f(f^{-1}(n_1))+f(f^{-1}(n_2)))= f^{-1}(f(f^{-1}(n_1)+f^{-1}(n_2)))=f^{-1}(n_1)+f^{-1}(n_2)$, where we use in the second equality that $f$ is a homomorphism. Can you now finish this?

Comment: @mathlife What is your definition of an isomorphism?

Comment: Homomorphism+bijection

Answer (score 2):

The answer is morally yes, but technically no, because equivalence relations technically have to be defined on *sets* and the collection of modules isn't a set. But nevertheless you can verify that all of the equivalence relation axioms hold, as in Ryszard's answer, if you ignore the distinction between sets and [proper classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)).

Comment: Exactly. I just came back to this question to say that! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am very late but I would like to answer this question.

**Definition:** Let $R$ be a ring and let $M$ and $N$ be $R-$modules.
A map $\psi:M\to N$ is an $R$-module isomorphism if $\psi$ is bijective and respects the $R$-module structures of $M$ and $N$, i.e.,

- $\psi(x+y)=\psi(x)+\psi(y), \forall x,y\in M$
- $\psi(rx)=r\psi(x),\forall r\in R,\forall m\in M.$
  I'll denote traditionally 'isomorphism' by $'\cong'$.
  Here we will show that $R$-module isomorphism is an equivalence relation.
  To prove this, we will show that$R$-module isomorphism is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

**Reflexivity:** Let $M$ be an $R$-module.
Let $i:M\to M$ be an identity map. $i$ is bijective and
$i(x+y)=x+y=i(x)+i(y), \forall x,y\in M$ and $i(rx)=rx=r(x),\forall r\in R, \forall x\in M$.
Thus $M\cong M.$

**Symmetry:** Let $M$ and $N$ be $R-$modules and $M$ is $R$-module isomorphic to $N$.
The map $\psi:M\to N $ is bijective and $R$-module homomorphism.
Now we claim that $N$ is $R$-module isomorphic to $M$.
Since $\psi$ is bijective therefore $\psi$ is invertible.
That is, $\psi^{-1}:N\to M$. It remains to show that $\psi^{-1}$ is $R$-module homomorphism.
\begin{equation*}\psi^{-1}(n_1+n_2)=\psi^{-1}(\psi(m_1)+\psi(m_2))=\psi^{-1}\psi(m_1+m_2)=m_1+m_2=\psi^{-1}(n_1)+\psi^{-1}(n_2).
\end{equation*}
**Transitivity:** Let $M,N$ and $O$ be $R$-modules.
We have $M$ is $R$-module isomorphic to $N$ and $N$ is $R$-module isomorphic to $O$. We'll claim that $M$ is $R$-module isomorphic to $O$.
$\phi:M\to N$, $\psi:N\to O$ and $\psi o\phi:M\to O$.
Let $h=\psi o\phi$. We know that composition of bijective maps is bijective. Therefore $h$ is bijective. Now we'll show that $h$ is $R$-module homomorphism,
\begin{equation}
h(m_1+m_2)=\psi o\phi(m_1+m_2)=\psi(\phi((m_1+m_2)))=\psi(\phi(m_1))+\psi(\psi(m_2))=h(m_1)+h(m_2)
\end{equation}.
I left condition second to prove in both symmetry and transitivity. That is pretty easy to do.